# I am trying to change patch color to signify the amount of a resource is increasing due to use by agents in my model

Tags: netlogo

I am using the Consumer store choice model by Yadov 2021 as my model base and reworking it to model the choice of consumers in regard to energy choices (gas, coal, nuclear etc.). The issue I have is finding a way to visually demonstrate the increase in the usage of a resource via patch color change as a function of consumer quantity.

I have set up a patches-own [ resource-area ] (similar to the ants model) and expect to see an increase in the color of patches surrounding the resources that I have set on the grid. The ant model reduces the amount of food by changing the color to black, I want to increase the size of a "mine" or "drill zone" by increasing the size of patches with the same color of that resource (gas = yellow , coal = black). I am not sure how to restructure the model to fit my needs without a complete tear-down and rebuild. Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

```
type here
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your goal here is. If you want to use discrete colors, then you can just set them. If you want continuous colors that scale up and down with a variable, you can use scale-color (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#scale-color) to change all pcolors each time you change the variables they should scale with.

Comment: Please summarize by asking a question in your title. What question would you like an answer to?

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the design of this model since and am no longer using this method. However, I was interested in knowing how to relate the size of an agent to the amount of links with other agents (to imply that a business, mine etc. is growing in value/use.)